# How to select the smallest number within one row in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data with multiple numbers in each row like this:

```
gene    numbers
P53     11 11 11 7 13 8 8
ACE     6 5 4 5 3
BRCA    2 2 1
```

I want the numbers column to only contain the smallest number that is in that row, with output being for example:

```
gene    numbers
P53     8
ACE     3
BRCA    1
```

I have looked into other answers on here, but most are for sorting through multiple rows and finding the smallest number in a column, as opposed to in one row.
For example I have tried using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0)
data = data.drop(["gene"],1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
matrix = df.as_matrix()
result1 = list(map(min, matrix))
result2 = list(map(min, zip(*matrix)))
```

However this gives an error that:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `data.min(axis=1)` should work

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately this does not change the output from the orginal format I have the data in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only column `numbers` filled by numbers splitted by whitespace first `split`, then convert to integers and get `min`:

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: min(map(int, x.split())))
print (df)
   gene  numbers
0   P53        7
1   ACE        3
2  BRCA        1
```

Another solution:

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.split(expand=True).astype(float).min(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   gene  numbers
0   P53        7
1   ACE        3
2  BRCA        1
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this it, the first one gives an error about strings and the second one gives: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer - is there anything I can do to get around this?

Comment: @DN1 - yes, if remove `.astype(int)` it working? `df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].str.split(expand=True).astype(float).min(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @DN1 - Reason was not working, because some `NaN`s, so problematic converting to integers.